# Google places shows blank

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use google places api but this is now working shows me Request_denied in android app and also in browser . please help

following this tutorial for google places
    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

```
{
"debug_info" : [],
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

i have generated key as following

[image]

and overview is this

[image]

and using this for testing

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBLW2RsxQuoZme-oy2t6ebRI7qyaOtMJq0

**EDIT :**

[image]

my permissions

```
<permission
    android:name="com.antheminfotech.locationnearby.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.antheminfotech.locationnearby.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

[image]

Comment: I am also facing same problem in androidhive. i just refer the following one to achieve http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: it work in all versions.

Comment: refer this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213687/google-place-api-always-return-this-status-request-denied?rq=1

Comment: there is also map not loaded due to my key

Comment: Sorry yaar i don't know the reason.

Comment: That project needs two keys

Comment: Browser API Key :for MainActivity.and Android API Key : for AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: see the above comment.

Comment: interesting because i'm also facing the same issue. Ok delete the project in google api and create new one it solved.

Comment: if i check my key on browser then also shown access_denied

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.6584917,76.818751&radius=5000&types=atm&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyACVXGWlyZWwmYh-jst7YkZmvEQ2ZwueyQ      . this is my Url get by debbing code

Comment: wait i will check my app and let you know.

Comment: in this reference you need to add the google play services library are you added.

Comment: yes i have already added

Comment: i got answer for your link..

Comment: Your area is chandigar right..

Comment: Problem is your key you need to put the correct keys.

Comment: yes, what is solution

Comment: yes m Rajpura job at zirakur

Comment: ok wait i update the answer.

Comment: hey please post ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project in google api provide the details like name and you package name and your sha1 key then click android in that. After that it show new key there you find generate new keys(browser,server,android) you can create the keys for both browser and android.

First enable the following services in google Api console

> 1.Google Maps API v2
>
> 2.Places API
>
> 3.Analytics API

```
<uses-permission android:name="(YourPackageName).permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

add this also

```
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Any problem to this let me know.

Comment: no, dnt show any error, only shows blank, in debugging i have check result come

Comment: Uninstall the project in your device and clean the project try now.

Comment: Check are you added the above permissions.

Comment: sounds like interesting..i got same but i forget what i did here ...find and inform.

Comment: sir please, bhut mushkil naal meri keys chal rahihan hn, problem map di hai , keys ok hn hun

Comment: Because i did same your wish....refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048381/google-maps-api-v2-shows-blank-map   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763789/google-map-displaying-only-blank-tiles-android

Comment: @Rohit i don't know hindi can you explain what you put in your comment...are you scolding or praising...... lol....just fun..

Comment: i have changed key but again same problem

Comment: On generating browser key, you can keep the url referer field as blank.

Comment: I think still the problem is key only you need to put the right key for manifest and main activity.

Comment: Please ensure the following :

Browser API Key : This is the key obtained in the class MainActivity.

Android API Key : This is the key obtained use it in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: android for menifest and browser key for class file

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.6535515,76.8207302&radius=5000&types=airport&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDhdaUpTdkBUCqr9x38wi01cU_SplC8ZD4
 

   . this is my url

Comment: make sure that your "user-permission" tags are outside <application></application>

Comment: refer this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/google-maps-android-api-v2-with-blank.html

Comment: 09-04 17:16:11.424: I/Google Maps Android API(5669): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

Comment: can you show your google api console services. In your question dashboard part.

Comment: enavle v2 instead of v3.

Comment: If you are using WIFI means you also need the android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in the manifest Don't know if it was just a case or it's a general thing

Comment: sir i have uninstall and reinstall but now left only to do restart eclipse

Comment: help please , not working , i have restarted eclipse and reinstall app

Comment: rohit@antheminfotech.com

Comment: i have replace only menifest key now

Comment: 09-04 18:13:24.764: E/AndroidRuntime(8115): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Comment: If found anything i will inform ok.

Comment: I solved the same problem here refer this ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618409/android-map-is-plain-white-screen-no-errors..

Comment: how this help me , wait i send u my full code, and please tell me whr m wrong

Comment: on my end this app is also not running 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: your keys are the problem in manifest and mainactivity you are using the same key. Yesterday itself i told to change the keys man.

Comment: bro i have changed, for testing now i was change it now

Comment: please check in sdk are you install the google play services or not

Comment: i have send you one more snapshot in mail