# Android Map is plain white screen - no errors

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

XML (activity_maptest.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Java (Maptest.java):

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Maptest extends Activity {

    public class MapActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maptest);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    .
    .
    .
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        .
        .
        .
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Maptest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maptest" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY ACTUAL KEY" />
    </application>
```

When this page is loaded in my page is just white and there are no errors LogCat. I was following the google guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, but it appears I did something wrong?

Comment: This caused due to key. You can recreate the keys and uninstall the app and try again.

Comment: Do you mean recreate the key in the google APIs console?

Comment: yes google APIs console keys.

Comment: It seems that that was not my issue. I made a new key and am still having the problem.

Comment: Add the permissions <permission
        android:name="(YourPackageName).permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="(YourPackageName).permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/><uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

Comment: Refer this for google maps http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: the MAPS_RECEIVE permission is obsolete as of Google Play Services 3.1.59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an Activity inside an Activity. Try removing one of them

Comment: I don't think I do. The activity's parent is the application.

Comment: Oh man. Sorry, I thought you were referring to the manafest. You are correct. Fixed that issue. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this combined with regenerating my key fixed my issue. I will happily mark this though.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue the problem I had was That I forgot to enable google Map APi from developer console :-

[image: enable api from console]

hope it will help somebody.