# Map is not displaying white screen - no errors

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

There were several questions like this, but neither of them was helpful for me. My problem is that map is not displaying (white screen) and no errors are displayed in the log. I added one Fragment in my app lately, before that the map was displaying just fine. What I have tried already:

1. Checked if google maps android API is enabled in google developers console.It's enabled.
2. Re-created google-services.json file and added in app folder.
3. Re-generated google_maps_key and pasted in google_map_api.xml file.
4. Changed deprecated getMap method with getMapAsync. There is no errors displayed so I'm really confused.

`MapsActivity`:

```
    package com.example.gio.autostop;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {


    public int permissionRequestCounter;
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public Boolean startedLocationUpdate;
    public LocationRequest locationRequest;
    public Location mCurrentLocation;
    public LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public final static int MILISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    public final static int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    public final static int MINUTE = 60 * MILISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;
    protected final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected static final String ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY = "address-request-pending";
    protected static final String LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY = "location-address";
    protected static final String TAG = "main-activity";
    public AddressFragment AddressFragment;


    private GoogleMap mMap;// Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private Button checkInButton,checkOutButton;
    private ArrayList<Marker> markerCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    private Marker  markerForDeletion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        checkInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        checkOutButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            AddressFragment addressFragment1=new AddressFragment();
            addressFragment1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,addressFragment1).commit();
        }
        AddressFragment =(AddressFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.AddressFragment);
        AddressFragment.setMapsActivity(this);
        startedLocationUpdate = false;
        permissionRequestCounter = 0;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(MINUTE);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * MILISECONDS_PER_SECOND);
        locationRequest.setPriority(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            checkGps();
        }

        deviceUniqueNumber();
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
        checkInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkInCurrentPosition();
                checkInButton.setClickable(false);
                checkOutButton.setClickable(true);
            }
        });
        checkOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deletePosition();
                markerForDeletion.remove();
                checkOutButton.setClickable(false);
                checkInButton.setClickable(true);
            }
        });
        checkOutButton.setClickable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !startedLocationUpdate)
            startLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (!startedLocationUpdate)
            startLocationUpdates();
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {

            if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_geocoder_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
//            AddressFragment gettingAddressFragment=(AddressFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (AddressFragment.mAddressRequested) {
                AddressFragment.startIntentService();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
//            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
//                    .getMapAsync(this);
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        startedLocationUpdate = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && startedLocationUpdate)
            stopLocationUpdates();

    }


    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, MapsActivity.this);
                startedLocationUpdate = true;
            } else {
                if (permissionRequestCounter == 0) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                    permissionRequestCounter++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();

    }

    public void enableMyLocation() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission to access the location is missing.
                if (permissionRequestCounter == 0) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
                    permissionRequestCounter++;
                }
            } else if (mMap != null) {
                // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length == 1
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    enableMyLocation();
                    checkGps();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Permission was blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        checkGps();
        return false;
    }

    public void checkGps() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        AddressFragment.fetchAddressHandler();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(s);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
                        JSONObject jsonObject;
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String mac = jsonObject.getString("mac");
                            String android_id = jsonObject.getString("android_id");
                            Double latitude = jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");
                            Double longitude = jsonObject.getDouble("longitude");
                            if (!isMarkerOnArray(markerCollection, latitude, longitude))
                                markerCollection.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))));
                        }

                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Downloading position failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        DownloadPosition downloadPosition = new DownloadPosition(responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
        queue.add(downloadPosition);


    }

    private boolean isMarkerOnArray(ArrayList<Marker> array, Double Latitude, Double Longitude) {
        Marker current;
        for (int c = 0; c < array.size(); c++) {
            current = array.get(c);
            if ((current.getPosition().latitude == Latitude) && (current.getPosition().longitude == Longitude))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY, startedLocationUpdate);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(LOCATION_KEY, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY, AddressFragment.mAddressRequested);
        savedInstanceState.putString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY, AddressFragment.mAddressOutput);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY))
                startedLocationUpdate = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY))
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY)) {
                AddressFragment.mAddressRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY);
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY)) {
                AddressFragment.mAddressOutput = savedInstanceState.getString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY);
                AddressFragment.displayAddressOutput();
            }

        }

    }






    public void checkInCurrentPosition() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location locationGPS = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location locationNet = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Location location;
        long GPSLocationTime = 0;
        if (null != locationGPS) { GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime(); }

        long NetLocationTime = 0;

        if (null != locationNet) {
            NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
        }

        if ( 0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime ) {
            location=locationGPS;
        }
        else {
            location=locationNet;
        }
        LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        markerForDeletion=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng).title(newLatLng.toString()));
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Positions position=new Positions(newLatLng.latitude,newLatLng.longitude,getWifiMacAddress(),deviceId);
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse= new JSONObject(s);
                    boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if(!success){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("uploading position failed")
                        .setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
                         }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        UploadPosition upload=new UploadPosition(position,responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
        queue.add(upload);

    }
    public void deletePosition(){
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String mac=getWifiMacAddress();
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse= new JSONObject(s);
                    boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if(!success){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("uploading position failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        DeletePosition delete=new DeletePosition(mac,deviceId,responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
        queue.add(delete);
    }


    public void deviceUniqueNumber(){
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        Toast.makeText(this,deviceId+" "+getWifiMacAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        public static String getWifiMacAddress() {
        try {
            String interfaceName = "wlan0";
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName)){
                    continue;
                }
                byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
                if (mac==null){
                    return "";
                }

                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte aMac : mac) {
                    buf.append(String.format("%02X:", aMac));
                }
                if (buf.length()>0) {
                    buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length() - 1);
                }
                return buf.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("getWifiMacAddress","exception in getWifiMacAddress");
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

`AndroidManifet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gio.autostop" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService" android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`activity_map.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<fragment class="com.example.gio.autostop.AddressFragment"
    android:id="@+id/AddressFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.gio.autostop.MapsActivity"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/map_interface"/>
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_address_fragment"/>
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

module:app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gio.autostop"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'

}
```

module:project `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()


    }
}
```

strings.xml

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">AutoStop</string>
    <string name="google_app_key">11117188100</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="Settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
    <string name="address_found">Address found</string>
    <string name="no_address_found">Sorry, no address found</string>
    <string name="no_geocoder_available">No geocoder available</string>
    <string name="no_location_data_provided">No location data provided</string>
    <string name="service_not_available">Sorry, the service is not available</string>
    <string name="invalid_lat_long_used">Invalid latitude or longitude used</string>
    <string name="check_in">Check in</string>
    <string name="my_location">My Location</string>
    <string name="check_out">check out</string>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
</resources>
```

**Edit:**
Log: http://codepad.org/hNdYhc0a

Comment: put logs, or make sure your sha1 is porper

Comment: are you replace your new google map api key in your string file ?

Comment: You need google map api key for debug mode.

Comment: I replaced google_maps_key in google_maps_api.xml. Should I put this key in strings.xml file too?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, encountered problem with the display can be prevented with the proper configuration when using Google Maps Android API. For the complete guide, you may refer to [Project Configuration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config).

Additionally, solutions given in this SO posts - [Google maps V2 showing a white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429650/google-maps-v2-showing-a-white-screen) or this [Android Map is plain white screen - no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618409/android-map-is-plain-white-screen-no-errors) might also help.