# Authendication failure in using google maps v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Following google maps tutorial .done step by step with out any error means double checked creating SHA1 and app key .but every time getting same white screen suggest me solution for this 
Logs

```
    09-26 17:51:49.911: E/Google Maps Android API(15187): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
09-26 17:51:49.911: E/Google Maps Android API(15187): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, API Key: AIzaSyBpo78ZEtJqgoYkR1dAm_9yEBcVWOJjagM, Certificate Fingerprint: 15F6E8976459BDE99D98F909E6B47744313D3E59
```

and here is my screen
[image]

Comment: this shows your problem is your API keys.

Comment: refer this one same problem like yours..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609772/google-places-shows-blank/18611852#18611852

Comment: Uninstall the app and then install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, On the google api console, there is two google map api v2's. It had the one just for google maps api v2 if you look just above it, it says google maps v2 android. Please turned on that one as well and the map is running.