# I'm trying to develop my first android app but my Google maps won't show

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm trying to develop my first android app but my Google maps won't show i get a gray screen.

I look around this forum but can't find a solution to solve my problem.

I think that i have set every thing right in my project (Eclipse) and in Google API Console. Have no error when testing my app (on real device galaxy s3 mini)

This is what i get in my  LogCat:

```
(Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.xxxxxxxxx, API Key: AIzaSyCsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXLZYdXr8, Certificate Fingerprint: DF6E6ECF6BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0F2E5 )
```

The Package Name is correct, Api Key is correct, Certificate Fingerprint is wrong i have never use this Certificate Fingerprint.
So i create a new Certificate use the SHA1 Fingerprint to create a new Api key past in manifest.xml

In LogCat now i have new api key but not a new Certificate Fingerprint, the Certificate Fingerprint is the same like before.

Is that Normal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'raid'?

Comment: refer this one..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609772/google-places-shows-blank/18611852#18611852